# Trigger airflow DAG manually with parameter and pass then into python function

Tags: python, airflow

I want to pass parameters into airflow DAG and use them in python function. I can use the parameter into bash operator, but I can’t find any reference to use them as python function.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

#Define DAG
dag = DAG("test_backup", schedule_interval=None, start_date=days_ago(1))

#Parameter
owner="{{ dag_run.conf['owner'] }}"
table="{{ dag_run.conf['table'] }}"

run_this="echo "+owner+"."+table

def test_func(owner,table):
    print(owner+"."+table)

task1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='test_task1',
    bash_command=run_this,
    dag=dag,
    queue='cdp_node53',
) 

task2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='test_task2',
   python_callable=test_func(owner,table),
    dag=dag,
    queue='cdp_node53',
)
```

I want to pass below as parameters while trigger DAG. "task1" works fine for me. I need to make "task2" workable. Please guide me to correct the above code so that I can pass parameters into it.

```
{"owner":"test_owner","table":"test_table"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For passing arguments into the `PythonOperator` you should use either `op_args` (for positional arguments) or `op_kwargs` (for keyword arguments).  Both parameters are also template fields so the values can be Jinja expressions as well.

Refactoring your code using `op_kwargs`:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


#Define DAG
dag = DAG("test_backup", schedule_interval=None, start_date=days_ago(1))

#Parameter
owner="{{ dag_run.conf['owner'] }}"
table="{{ dag_run.conf['table'] }}"

run_this="echo "+owner+"."+table

def test_func(owner,table):
    print(owner+"."+table)

task1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='test_task1',
    bash_command=run_this,
    dag=dag,
    queue='cdp_node53',
)

task2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='test_task2',
    python_callable=test_func,
    op_kwargs={"owner": owner, "table": table},
    dag=dag,
    queue='cdp_node53',
)
```

Both tasks will log the `INFO - test_owner.test_table` now.