# How to pass optional parameters to Airflow PythonOperator when triggering DAG manually?

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to pass **optional** parameters to a DAG I plan to trigger manually, using `Trigger DAG w/ config`. It uses `PythonOperator`.

I followed an [answer by J.Fell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67826190/9855909) where it is suggested to explicitly access the passed parameters from `dag_run.conf`

```
param1="{{ dag_run.conf['param1'] }}"
param2="{{ dag_run.conf['param2'] }}"
```

When I trigger my DAG that runs a function with optional parameter (`param2`), passing only: `{"param1":"value1"}`

I get an error:

```
UndefinedError: 'dict_object' has no attribute 'param2'
```

How can I adjust accessing the values from `dag_run.conf` so that optional parameters will not throw an error?

#### DAG Code Example

```
__version__ = "@version@"

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
import sys
import socket
import datetime
import my_function

file_name = my_function.get_file_name(__file__)

dag = DAG(
    dag_id = file_name,
    default_args=my_function.default_args,
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval=None,
    tags = ['my_function']
)

# Parameters
param1="{{ dag_run.conf['param1'] }}"
param2="{{ dag_run.conf['param2'] }}"

custom_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id = "custom_task",
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=my_function.main,
    op_kwargs= {**{'param1': param1, 'param2': param2},
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS
)

custom_task
```

Comment: please post DAG code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to achieve this:

1. Using `dag_run.conf`:

```py
param2="{{ dag_run.conf['param2'] if 'param2' in dag_run.conf else 'default_value' }}"
```

2. Using `Params`:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id = file_name,
    default_args=my_function.default_args,
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval=None,
    tags = ['my_function'],
    params={
        "param1": "default_value",
        "param2": "default_value",
    }
)

# Parameters
param1="{{ params.param1 }}"
param2="{{ params.param2 }}"
```

But you need to check that [core.dag_run_conf_overrides_params](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/params.html#disabling-runtime-param-modification) is not set to `False` (it's by default `True`)